# Java - Selenium - Error while running

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

ERROR - Single click action failed: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.moveToElement(Actions.java:257) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]

---

```
public static void singleClickUsingAction(WebDriver driver, WebElement webElement)
    {
        try {
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(webElement);
            actions.click().build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Single click action failed: ", e);
        }
    }
```

Could someone help figure out the issue ? I'm using Chrome driver latest version in my local machine to execute this.

Comment: change `actions.moveToElement(webElement);` to `actions.moveToElement(webElement).build();`

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I used in different ways- actions.moveToElement(webElement).build(); actions.moveToElement(webElement).perform();   but it didn't help much!  Still I have the issue